# How to Print a specific dictionary-key from output in Python [not working]

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote this code to convert audio to text using Deepgram and print only the transcripted text from the Dictionary in the result. I'm using this code:

```py
 response = await dg_client.transcription.prerecorded(source,  options)
    print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))

    print(response.keys())
    print(response['results']['channels']['alternatives']['transcript'])
```

But this one is not working. I removed the last 2 keys (`['alternatives']['transcript']`) and then, it works. Here's the dictionary in the output:

```
 "results": {
        "channels": [
            {
                "alternatives": [
                    {
                        "transcript": "Yep. I said it before, and I'll say it again. Life moves pretty fast. You don't stop and look around once in a while. You could miss it.",
                        "confidence": 0.9935537
                    }]
```

Please help, thank you in advance!

Comment: `'channels'` is a list, not a dict (so is `'alternatives'`). Either iterate over it or index into the one you want, in this case it is probably `response['results']['channels'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']`

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life! I really didn't saw it

Answer (score 1):

Values from keys `channels` and `alternatives` are arrays, so you may index it with int

---

To get first one in both arrays

```
response['results']['channels'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
```

To display all, use loops

```
for channel in response['results']['channels']:
    for alternative in channel['alternatives']:
        print(alternative['transcript'])
```